# Amazon s3 putObject returns 403 when image name contains accented characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon AWS service to upload images. Everything works fine but amazon s3 putObject returns 403 when image name contains accented characters.

Exception (AmazonS3Client.java):

```
try {
        returnedMetadata = invoke(request, new S3MetadataResponseHandler(), bucketName, key); // Exception is throws here
     } catch (Throwable t) {
        publishProgress(listener, ProgressEventType.TRANSFER_FAILED_EVENT);
        throw failure(t);
     }
```

> Failed to upload image with fileName: Credilogic rögzítés_2.png The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: D0AA66769D176AE9; S3 Extended Request ID: ul29eQUiECjkTr3gDbIAxyd7OlTH818yVVlyY5yiRkk20vffsaRcOWcZpoK4ayJ5RbeaVScBqQ0=)

```
amz-sdk-invocation-id:20a1234a-9e72-4549-a716-1508c9782f22
amz-sdk-retry:3/86/443
cache-control:no-cache
content-length:58726
content-type:image/png
host:inline.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.11.392 Windows_Server_2012_R2/6.3          
Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.181-b13 java/1.8.0_181 groovy/2.5.2
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20181214T065845Z
x-amz-meta-created:Fri Dec 14 06:56:23 GMT 2018
x-amz-meta-originalname:Credilogic r�gz�t�s_2.png
x-amz-server-side-encryption:AES256
```

We can see x-amz-meta-originalname:Credilogic r�gz�t�s_2.png has accented characters.

Comment: Have you tried without an accent? 403 generally pertains to permission issues, so you might not have access to the bucket.

Comment: @GaryHoliday note that `SignatureDoesNotMatch` has a specific meaning -- the signature accompanying the request is not consistent with the actual request being made or the secret key accompanying the access key used to sign the request was incorrectly specified (e.g. a copy/paste error in the secret key).  It is not a permissions issue.

Comment: Without accented characters everything works fine.